# How do I get text to flow around a div above and below?

Tags: html, css, styles

I want to basically have this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                               |
| Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text   |
| Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text   |
|---------------------| Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text |
|                     | Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text |
|     DIV             | Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text |
|                     | Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text |
|---------------------| Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text |
| Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text   |
| Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

it's easy enough to float the div to the left and have the text flow underneath it, but I need the text to flow from the left above it as well.

This is what I have so far, I just have no idea where to go from here: http://jsfiddle.net/x7HFZ/2/

ALSO, the text will be dynamic, and I need the div's position to be fixed.

Comment: jsFiddle has a section for CSS. You should be using that instead of inline styles for easy editing.

Comment: Move `#panel2ColLeft` downward in the lipsum text.

Comment: @sachleen Not only jsFiddle. You can use that in real life web pages as well. ;-)

Comment: Rest assured the real-life page will be using a style sheet, in-line styles just help me figure things out when I have a layout conundrum like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the div in the middle of the text:

http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/x7HFZ/14/

Comment: Assuming the text will be dynamic, any idea how i could "fix" the position of the div?

Comment: You can't, unless you find a way to put that html somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @invertedSpear Even if the text is dynamic, inserting it in a specific position in the HTML won't affect the `div`s position.

Comment: @Abody97 Yes it will, because to get the desired result, the div must be somewhere inbetween the text, which is harder if you must use dynamic texts from a CMS or any source alike.

Comment: yup, not the answer my design department wants, but can only do so much. I can guestimate the position by counting characters as it looks like it will just float to the left of whatever line it's inserted on, but the idea that it could shift up or down a line is not appealing. C'est la vie. Thank you GolezTrol.